# How to use an installer to install more than one installation in a simple .exe file?

Tags: java, mysql, deployment, installation, inno-setup

I am working on Java rich client app. with MySQL server and I made it as `.jar` file.
I want the user to have one simple `.exe` file that when running it, install JRE and MySQL server then he'll have a shortcut for the jar file and simply work on it.

I tried to use more than installer: inno setup, advanced installer, Excelsior Installer, ...
but they're all give me the same result: just put all `.exe` files for JRE and MySQL server in the destination folder after installing the product (i.e. just unpack files without installing them).

Can anybody help me?

Comment: *"I want the user to have one simple .exe file"*  That is no use to the end-user of Mac or *nix based machines.

Comment: Hi, Andrew... Java Web Start? :)

Comment: yes, the application have a GUI, and it doesn't indeed require JDK to run or work but i want it for just test something

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Ah, I am just pulling your legs. Anyway, it's "ee." not "ee", but I also have another two unregistered accounts named "eee". I don't know whether SO can merge these three unregistered accounts together or not like before.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I did expect you to post something on JWS ;) Stop now since this is like chatting now...hahah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run as many executables as you want (Windows setup installers are executables) under `[Run]` in InnoSetup script file when creating you setup file via InnoSetup. But, you shall use `Check:` to check whether each installer has been installed or not.

Example installing Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) run-time and Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) with registry check on target system:

```
[Files]
Source: "install\README.txt"; DestDir: "{app}" Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "install\vcredist_x86.exe"; DestDir: "{app}" Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createsubdirs
Source: "install\jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe"; DestDir: "{app}" Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram, {#MyTitleName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Comment: "Uninstalls {#MyTitleName}"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\vcredist_x86.exe"; StatusMsg: {cm:RunVCRedist2010x86}; Flags: runhidden shellexec waituntilterminated; Check: IsNotVCRedist2010x86Installed
Filename: "{app}\jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe"; StatusMsg: {cm:RunJAIByDefault}; Flags: runhidden shellexec waituntilterminated; Check: IsNotJAIInstalled

[Code]
function IsNotJAIInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\SUNW\Java Advanced Imaging');
end;

function IsNotVCRedist2010x86Installed: Boolean;
var
  Installed: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86',
    'Installed', Installed) and (Installed <> 1);
end;
```

**Note:**
If your installers in `[Files]` are located in the "install" folder of your InnoSetup project, they are compressed during Innosetup process to generate your the InnoSetup setup executable. When you run the setup created, it will uncompress the installers in your defined `{app}` folder and it will execute whatever defined under `[Run]`

Comment: it's my first time with inno so i don't know much of this stuff, i have wrote this 


[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, "&", "&&")}}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent
Filename: "{app}\JRE_1_5_.exe"; Parameters: "--install MyApp_JRE_1_5_" 
Filename: "{app}\JDK_6_WI.exe"; Parameters: "--install MyApp_JDK_6_WI" 

is this right or wrong and if wrong how can i write it ??

Comment: When you run InnoSetup to compile your InnoSetup script file, it produces events. If there is something wrong, we can tell from this InnoSetup event trace

Comment: Is there another installer working in GUI without need to write code??
IS Excelsior Installer do the job I want??

Comment: Code writing is only needed on rare cases like in my example above where certain installers can't notify user properly if they have been installed before (it's not InnoSetup fault). I believe all setup creation software have some coding to tackle this issue.

Comment: if I don't want to check whether this have been installed before or not, what to do to setup more than one file??

Comment: You can do so like you want but it gives the user a burden to wait for all installation steps to finish. By checking this before hand, we can skip those installers that have been installed before...

Comment: The problem is when I do the normal steps to create the desired exe file it doesn't make what i want, as I said previously, it doesn't install anything and put all exe files in the destination folder as they are without installation
what's the mistake I do??

Comment: You need to look where you put your all installer files that you want to distribute to user in your InnoSetup under [Files]. I will update this info in the example above

Comment: so, how to uninstall them?
I wrote this
[UninstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\JRE_1_5_.exe";
but it doesn't work

Comment: **Correction of deleted comment** You don't have to. Everything install will be uninstalled unless you define in `Flags:` with value `uninsneveruninstall` in each InnoSetup entry. It will cause InnoSetup not to uninstall it. I will include an entry to create InnoSetup uninstaller under `[Icons]`

Answer (score 0):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) are the obvious choices for this deployment.

1. Use `deployJava.js` to ensure the user has the right minimum version of the JRE to run the app.
2. Call the MySQL installer using the [`ExtensionInstallerService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).
3. (If necessary) store any installation specific data (e.g. the path the user chose to install the DB) using the [`PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).
4. Specify desktop shortcuts and menu items in the launch file.

Note that if you can supply an installer for MySQL on Mac. and *nix, JWS can partition the download by OS.